# Difference between [shutdown] and [system-shutdown]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

What's the difference between [shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shutdown) and [system-shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-shutdown)?

1/3 (16/43) of the questions that are tagged with [system-shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-shutdown) [are also tagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-shutdown+shutdown) with [shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shutdown), so I don't think the difference between those tags is very clear to most people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose that we should merge [system-shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-shutdown) into [shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shutdown).

[shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shutdown) is still a horrible tag though. I have a hard time seeing any value in it.

---

```
updating post history, 54 rows affected
updating posts, 44 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 28 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [shutdown] and [system-shutdown] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Comment: +1 for merging. I am OK with the shutdown tag though. I have sometimes had problems shutting down my computer cleanly. On Linux, for example, I have seen slow shutdown times that depended on mounted NFS voumes. It seems a valid enough tag.